# gulp deploy rsync error // missing module lodash

Tags: gulp, jekyll, rsync

I am trying to deploy my project via rsync. I have a gulp install with jekyll. I installed the "missing" module lodash globally and in the project folder but no change of the error. Any ideas what to try next?!

```
    module.js:338
    throw err;
          ^
Error: Cannot find module 'lodash._getnative'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/node_modules/gulp/node_modules/gulp-util/node_modules/lodash.template/node_modules/lodash.keys/index.js:9:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

This is in my gulpfile.js

```
var rsync = require('rsyncwrapper').rsync;
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

gulp.task('deploy', function() {
  rsync({
    ssh: false,
    src: './build/',
    dest: '***@***:/***/***/',
    recursive: true,
    syncDest: true,
    args: ['--verbose']
  }, function(error, stdout, stderr, cmd) {
      gutil.log(stdout);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If found the solution :) There has been an error in the modules. So i deleted every node_modules folder and reinstalled. Now it it working

Comment: can i ask where you deleted them from? Similar issue here and tried deleting local & global node_modules  folders.  ( at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:4:13))

Comment: i deleted them in the root 'node_modules' folder